# Math formulas needed to design an Alternator from scratch

Tags: voltage, amperage, alternator

I'm trying to create electricity using an alternator but I require a few formulas.

Are there formulas to calculate:

Thickness of wire required.

Winding's of copper around magnet required.

Size of magnet required.

Type of magnets required.

To produce, let's say, 2400 amps @ 240 volts.

Sorry if the question is unclear or if the question doesn't belong here.

Note: I'm still a beginner.

**Edit**

Sorry I'm a little mad. Is 500 amps possible?

Comment: You want to build an alternator from scratch? You are beginner and barely know anything about electromagnetic and you expect to have a 2400 amps / 240 volts? Seriously, it take a whole team of engineer and here I talk about electric engineer, mechanical engineer & material engineer to achieve that. Not to mention all the people with more technical knownledge in the production part....

Comment: Do you have any idea what you are asking?  A half megawatt generator isn't something you slap together in your garage.

Comment: So sorry guys, how about 500amps?

Comment: Well, there you are looking at at least 1000MCM 'wire' to wind the stator.  How many poles? What is your prime mover? What is your target frequency?

Comment: You are not giving up easily, do you?

Comment: No @EugeneSh. I'm thinking

Comment: @RDrast I unfortunately can't leak my prime mover. 50 hertz.

Comment: Leak? Seriously? Sounds a lot like a 'free energy' scheme.  Give up now.  And 240 is an odd voltage for 50 Hz.

Comment: @RDrast Should we expect a question about how to build a motor ?

Comment: Why is 240 an odd voltage for 50Hz? That's UK mains.

Comment: I'm not getting funny, but is someone going to give me formulas or not?

Comment: @DilanV - Basically the two formulae you need are V=IR and F=BLI.  But I can 100% confidently predict that you will fail to build anything generating 2400A, 500A or 50A or even 5A at 240V.  Your reach exceeds your grasp.

Comment: What if I generate a small voltage and step up the voltage?

Answer (score 3):

Here's what a 500kW alternator looks like (right hand side):

[image: http://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/500kw-VOLVO-generator-alternator_60226292551/showimage.html]

This one is attached to a giant Volvo turbocharged diesel engine to drive it. 500kW is almost 700HP.

If you really need such a thing it will be cheaper to buy it.

Answer (score 1):

There are people who've built small alternators for wind power, such as http://www.instructables.com/id/DIY-1000-watt-wind-turbine/ and http://www.windstuffnow.com/main/alt_from_scratch.htm - if I were you I'd start with one of those and follow all the links to theory of operation.

Note that you're trying to get at least four design variables out of two target design variables; you'll need to constrain more to work out an example. Such as generator RPM.

(How on earth are you going to drive this thing? Train-sized diesel generator? Edit: comparing with Deltic locomotives, which have about 2MW, I'd say you're looking at several tons of alternator.)